# How to Remove Element / Component from BlazorWebassambly

Tags: razor, components, blazor, element

I am trying to make a Razor component that removes itself from the page after 3 seconds, after its added to the page.

1. I will click on a button
2. Than the Component will be added to the current page
3. After 3 seconds the Component removes itselfrom the page

```
<**div @ref="messageRef" style="position: absolute; margin: 0 auto; background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 80px;">**

    <p>Message.....</p>
</div>

@code {
    ElementReference messageRef;

    private MessageComponent thisMsg;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("MessageComponent.Remove()", messageRef); 
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a simple Blazor `if` statement would work to remove the div and paragraph from the DOM here, or is there a reason you're trying to remove the component itself? Which, btw, I don't believe is possible to do from the inside the component itself - you would have to do this at the parent level where this component's calling-markup exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As JeremyW mentions in his comment, this can be done with an `@if` statement in the body of the page that holds the content. Using the Blazor template app as an example, it might look something like this:

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@if (displayPrompt)
{
    <SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
}

@code {
    private bool displayPrompt;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        displayPrompt = true;
        HideMessageAfterDelay();
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private async void HideMessageAfterDelay()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        displayPrompt = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

When `displayPrompt` evaluates to `true`, the prompt is added to the DOM. When is evaluates to `false`, it's removed from the DOM.

If you need the message component to handle this itself, then just put the equivalent code inside the component itself instead of the page.